# How can I connect a golo4 obd2 device with IBM IoT platform without using a mobile application?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

I'm using IBM Bluemix Services to develop a real time application. While developing the application I need to analyse the device data (Golo4 obd2 device) on the IoT platform. Please guide me to the step-by-step information regarding the connection of the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have one of those devices but from a quick google it seems the only way to connect it to the web is via a mobile app they provide.  Perhaps you can ask the manufacture or check the instruction manual?  There is no way to analyze the data in bluemix if you can't get it from the car to bluemix.  It is a common architecture for this to be via a phone (bluetooth to the phone and then wifi or mobile network to the WWW).  Which is why it becomes important to consider the impact on the phone's battery life and the cost to the user of the amount of data transferred and minimize both.

Comment: hi can you please check this video from IBM